# How to get Visible PivotField Object from a PivotTable object in C#(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel)

Tags: c#, excel

```
 PivotTables pt = worksheet.PivotTables();
 var pivot = pt.Item(1);
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields pf= 
(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields)pivot.VisibleFields();
```

The above snippet was supposed to return a collection of the visible fields in a pivot table, but **MissingMemberException** (*Error while invoking [PROPERTYGET, DISPID(0)].*) is generated, but the following code works perfectly:

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields pf= 
  (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields)pivot.PivotFields();
```

I want only the visible fields in the table and not all the fields.

Comment: Did something change because I can't access the PivotFields object at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the biggest challenges I have in converting VBA to C# is the way VBA blurs the lines between when functions that need need parentheses and others that don't.

As a result, when a function has no parameters and doesn't need parentheses, it looks more like a property.  Such is the case with `PivotFields`.

So all that said, `PivotFields()` in C# is indeed a *method*, so your syntax above is correct.  However, `VisibleFields` is a *Property*, not a method, so you need to omit the parentheses to make it work:

```
Excel.PivotTables pt = worksheet.PivotTables();
var pivot = pt.Item(1);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotFields vf = pivot.VisibleFields;
                                       // not   pivot.VisibleFields();
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.PivotField f in vf)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Crazy, right?